# Can one half of a planet be desolate, while the other half is lush vegetation?

Tags: science-based, magic, science-fiction, sunlight, tidally-locked

Is it possible for half a planet to be cold, dark and lifeless while the other is a lush jungle? Can a planet be tidally locked to a sun where the jungle surface is always facing the light, and the other side is facing away? This'll create the contrast, however would plants be able to survive if they're always dealing with sunlight, and will animals be able to live without night?

If it's possible, how different from "earth standard" would the planet's life be like? I'm afraid it might be too hot, unless the planet is far enough away from the sun. I think the only way there'd be dark is if there's a moon or another celestial object that blocks the path from the sun to the planet, making "night" a rare event. And lastly, if I'm correct, wind is caused by the uneven heating of the Earth's surface, so would there be wind if the same part of the planet is always facing the sun?

Edit: Also, what would it be like to live in a valley placed on the equator of the planet, a division between the light and the dark?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of whether a planet tidally locked to its star would be capable of supporting life has been a topic of scientific discussion.

> Astronomers for many years ruled out red dwarfs as potential abodes for life. Their small size (from 0.08 to 0.45 solar masses) means that their nuclear reactions proceed exceptionally slowly, and they emit very little light (from 3% of that produced by the Sun to as little as 0.01%). Any planet in orbit around a red dwarf would have to huddle very close to its parent star to attain Earth-like surface temperatures; from 0.3 AU (just inside the orbit of Mercury) for a star like Lacaille 8760, to as little as 0.032 AU for a star like Proxima Centauri[84] (such a world would have a year lasting just 6.3 days). At those distances, the star's gravity would cause tidal locking. One side of the planet would eternally face the star, while the other would always face away from it. The only ways in which potential life could avoid either an inferno or a deep freeze would be if the planet had an atmosphere thick enough to transfer the star's heat from the day side to the night side, or if there was a gas giant in the habitable zone, with a habitable moon, which would be locked to the planet instead of the star, allowing a more even distribution of radiation over the planet. It was long assumed that such a thick atmosphere would prevent sunlight from reaching the surface in the first place, preventing photosynthesis.
>
> This pessimism has been tempered by research. Studies by Robert Haberle and Manoj Joshi of NASA's Ames Research Center in California have shown that a planet's atmosphere (assuming it included greenhouse gases CO2 and H2O) need only be 100 millibars (0.10 atm), for the star's heat to be effectively carried to the night side.[85] This is well within the levels required for photosynthesis, though water would still remain frozen on the dark side in some of their models. Martin Heath of Greenwich Community College, has shown that seawater, too, could be effectively circulated without freezing solid if the ocean basins were deep enough to allow free flow beneath the night side's ice cap. Further research—including a consideration of the amount of photosynthetically active radiation—suggested that tidally locked planets in red dwarf systems might at least be habitable for higher plants.[86]
> This pessimism has been tempered by research. Studies by Robert Haberle and Manoj Joshi of NASA's Ames Research Center in California have shown that a planet's atmosphere (assuming it included greenhouse gases CO2 and H2O) need only be 100 millibars (0.10 atm), for the star's heat to be effectively carried to the night side.[85] This is well within the levels required for photosynthesis, though water would still remain frozen on the dark side in some of their models. Martin Heath of Greenwich Community College, has shown that seawater, too, could be effectively circulated without freezing solid if the ocean basins were deep enough to allow free flow beneath the night side's ice cap. Further research—including a consideration of the amount of photosynthetically active radiation—suggested that tidally locked planets in red dwarf systems might at least be habitable for higher plants.[86]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_habitability#Size

See also here as a start in your research:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_red_dwarf_systems

And you should try to read the scientific papers cited  to see what they say, and especially what limitations they may place on the habitability of tidally locked worlds for different types of life.

I note that if all the characters in your story are natives of the planet, they will be used to it being tidally locked.  Unless any of them are scientists, they won't discuss various factors like the mass and diameter of their world, and its distance from its star, etc., and if they do they will use their units of measurment.

But if characters in your story are explorers or settlers from Earth, this could be the first tidally locked planet they have ever found, or the first one with life. Thus the characters might discuss the parameters of theplanet and how they effect its habitability in great length.  Or possibly they have found a lot of tidally locked planet, and classify them into various types, and a character might explain what makes this planet a member of one of the types of tidally locked planets which can support life.

In the second case you will need to design, or have someone more scientifically literate do it for you, a planet and star system which astrobiologists can accept could have life despite the planet being tidally locked.

Answer (score 4):

A tidally locked planet with a habitable zone would probably need to have *two* desolate parts, at the poles, and a marginally habitable equator in between.

Instead, use the distribution of continents and a mix of

- [Rain shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_shadow), mountain ridges causing rain in some places but not in others,
- extreme [continental climate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continental_climate), with few inland seas,
- [Tree line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_line), the altitude where the temperature limits the growth of large plants.

This won't give you the *dark* part along with cold and lifeless, and also no complete lifeless half, but compare the Amazon with Afghanistan.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible, for sure.

You're asking whether the kinds of plants and animals that *we* know of could survive in that kind of environment. But life evolves based on its local conditions. Your ecosystem would need to have evolved a bunch of adaptations to tolerate the stress of this world, but it's no different to, say, the species that have evolved to live on rocky sea shores (where there is continuous heating / drying out, changes in salinity and temperature, times of day when there is increased predation and so on). The day / night cycle in those environments is much less important than the water cycle.

On your planet, you might have a different kind of water cycle that regulates the ecosystem. For example, plants respire. In your world, anything that we recognise as a plant would overheat and dry out, so something needs to happen to stop this from happening. What would probably happen is that the change in atmospheric dynamics from one side of the planet to another would result in huge storms that would periodically block out the light, acting as short-term darkness and redistributing moisture back over the forest. Animals would probably adapt to use this time to sleep (or, in some rare cases, hunt). Any human-like or intelligent culture would probably build itself around those kinds of storms, setting their calendar or religion or whatever else accordingly.

This is just one example off the top of my head. An alternative is that you have a world of continuous growth on one side of the planet, that either is fed from melting aquifers at the terminator, or is self-regulating in some other way. For example, trees grow very quickly in continuous daylight, but also die quickly, meaning that their water and nutrients are rapidly recycled. You just need a mechanism for regulating the system otherwise all the water evaporates and life dies out.

Answer (score -1):

Plants can live under constant light even as is.

Animals would evolve differently, or will just sleep whenever they want, without circadian rithm.

Temperature is controlled by placing the planet further.

Wind will be present, but directed to and from hot and cold sides mostly.

Biggest problem will be loss of water, in a form of snow on the cold side. To the point when all the water is there. Or there is tens of km tall glacier over all of the cold side, so that air cant even get above of it.

Another problem is unevenness of temperature. The hotspot will be much hotter than the terminator - edge between light and dark sides. Biggest living area can be achieved if hotspot is a desolated desert, and then a ring of livable area around it.

Problem is that life emerging on such a planet is unlikely. Tidally locked planets are close to a star. Only red dwarfs are small enough, they are unstable and often would kill off the life periodically. And such position makes tides unfavorable for life. Less tectonic acticity also doesnt help. Chances to get a large moon are also much smaller.